# Android Text Display - Canvas.drawText() output pixelated

Tags: android, text, canvas

My Android app displays text in a few different ways, and there are some annoying differences between them I was hoping folks could help with.

When I use display methods that might be termed "automatic," the text is displayed very nicely.  By automatic methods, I'm referring tools, like Toasts and Button widgets where I just have supply the text, and the OS (or "environment" or whatever) displays it for me.  The letters are nicely curved, pleasant to look at, and easily legible.

However, in my code where I handle the text display (using `Canvas.drawText()` in a Surface Runner View), the text quality is poor.  The text is still legible, but it looks pixelated.  The letters just don't look their best.

I've tried experimenting with `Paint.setTypeface()`, using Typeface.SANS_SERIF for example, but the quality of the display when it's my code is always poor.  Doable, but poor.

Has anybody else experienced this?  By any chance does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might also try playing around with `Paint.setAntiAlias(boolean)` or `Paint.setSubpixelText(boolean)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what effect setSubpixelText() has on my code, but setAntiAlias() worked great -- on the text.  The graphics part of my code has a bit of stuff drawn on top of other stuff and if anti-aliasing was enabled for that the results looked, well, odd... However, it's not problem at all to toggle anti-aliasing on and off as necessary.  So, thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm actually not certain exactly what the subpixel text option does either. If I'm not mistaken, it's similar to Windows' ClearType rendering for LCD screens, but I couldn't find any real documentation on it.

Comment: `setSubpixelText` sets the SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG, which is (sparsely) documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG